# Where do Badass Marauders spawn on Pandora?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, I'm having a hard time tracking down which area Badass Marauders are local to on Pandora. I'm assuming they have the same spawn points as regular Marauders, but I'm still having a problem tracking them down.

Comment: Badass Marauders are a stronger breed of normal bandits. They do not spawn in some specific location, rather, all bandit-populated zones have a few. It would be hard to list all the exact spawn points, as they are many, and pointless, as there are only one or two guys in each. Example: the camp around Flynt's ship on Southern Shelf has one Badass Marauder right after Med Vendor.

Comment: Lots (including four at a time) of those guys appear in Bandit Slaughter quests, but they're not repeatable.

Comment: I should have made it less specific, as I know that general groups of enemies spawn together (psychos, bandits, marauders, bruiser, etc). I was just wondering which areas were specific to Bandit (and their Marauder subset) spawning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to farm them (3 to 4 guaranteed) is to head in Tundra express, at the north west of Tina cave you have a small camp with rat, kill them, find the valve that trigger the alarm. The alarm will spawn 3 wave of enemies and the last always spawn 3 to 4 Badass Marauder.

Watch this video for more details :

Comment: voted up for awesome answer, thanks for the video. I should try and start asking youtube before getting on this site sometimes.

Comment: Especially on games with a large community (like BL, Diablo etc.), you always have youtubers such as MorningAfterKill (who made this vdeo) that give you thos tips ^_-

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking because of the [loot challenge](https://www.borderlands2loothunt.com/challenge/2013-10-12), the easiest place to find them is [Blackburn Cove](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Southern_Shelf_-_Bay). After killing [Knuckle Dragger](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Knuckle_Dragger), continue on to — and through — Liar's Berg. Take an immediate left when exiting the Liar's Berg gate, and fight through to Southern Shelf - Bay. That puts you right outside Blackburn Cove.

I say "easiest" not just because it's proximate to the Knuckle Dragger fight location. The bad guys in this location will all be much lower level than you are, unless you just started a new character, so you can breeze right through the low-level enemies on your way to the Badass Marauders. Even [Midge-Mong](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Midge-Mong) will probably be a push-over.

There should be about four Badass Marauders in Blackburn Cove.

Two guaranteed are in the bar way up high, where the vending machines are. The bar door unlocks once you kill Midge-Mong, then the two marauders pop out from the room behind the bar just after you walk in.

The other(s) will be out in the marina after fighting past all the low-level bad guys.

Comment: The Loot Challenge was part of why I was asking the question, but getting the Badass Bingo challenge was also part of it, as Marauders are one of the lower level enemies on Pandora.

Comment: I completely forgot about mide-mong's area. That is a perfect place to farm early on in the game. Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Badass marauders is first found when your on your way to captian flynt but there is only one. If you want to find more go to the fridge in the slaughter house do the challenge there is a time where a lot of them spawns at the same time. But watch out they are not the only badasses.. There are also badass nomads, badass gloiaths and badass psychos..